# Codeigniter cart is just updated after refreshing page

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, codeigniter-2, shopping-cart, page-refresh

I'm using CI 2.1.3 for my shopping cart project. This is how add-to-cart works : call add_to_cart function to insert item into cart, then redirect to view_cart page. But the cart wasn't updated immediately. It is only updated when the page reloaded. Why?

```
public function add_to_cart($product_id){
        if (isset($product_id)){
            $product = $this->_product_model->get_record_by_id((int)$product_id);
            if (!is_null($product)){
                if (count($this->cart->contents())>0){
                    foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $item){
                        if ($item['id']==$product->id){
                            $data = array('rowid'=>$item['rowid'],'qty'=>++$item['qty']);
                            $this->cart->update($data);
                        }else{
                            $data = array('id'=>$product->id,'qty'=>1,'price'=>$product->price,'name'=>$product->id,'options'=>array('image'=>$product->thumb,'product_name'=>$product->title));
                            $this->cart->insert($data);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    $data = array('id'=>$product->id,'qty'=>1,'price'=>$product->price,'name'=>$product->id,'options'=>array('image'=>$product->thumb,'product_name'=>$product->title));
                    $this->cart->insert($data);
                }
                //$this->layout->load('cart/view_cart', $this->data);
                redirect(base_url('view_cart.html'),'location');
            }
        }else{
            $this->layout->load('/product/product_not_found', $this->data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you add an item to to cart, are directed to the cart page but the item isn't in your cart. You refresh the page, and it is in the cart?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
redirect(base_url('view_cart.html'),'refresh');
```

Comment: did you tried to use database for sessions ? probably you have too much data for session size.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html